# DateAdd function in pl/sql

Tags: plsql

As the title suggested , I am looking for a function in pl /sql  which does something similar like the DateAdd function. 
I have been looking and I found the add_months function but I would really like one that is a little more variable since I need to be able to add minutes, hours , days etc.

Comment: Give me $100 and I'll not only give you a DateAdd function, but also NumberAdd, NumberSubstract, NumberMultiply, NumberDivide... on top of that, I'll even throw in functions that will allow you to add **three** numbers together in one function call, for free! ;)

Comment: You already told me to give you 100$ ;) , so wouldn't be for free ;). Thanks for the reply though. I created a function myself which does the same thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent function for DATEADD() in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405297/equivalent-function-for-dateadd-in-oracle)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears there's not many solutions :

> PL/SQL allows you to perform arithmetic operations directly on date variables. You may add numbers to a date or subtract numbers from a date. To move a date one day in the future, simply add 1 to the date as shown below:

```
hire_date + 1
```

> You can even add a fractional value to a date. For example, adding 1/24 to a date adds an hour to the time component of that value. Adding 1/(24*60) adds a single minute to the time component, and so on.

Comment: mmm ok.  So only workarounds in this area huh;).  Thanks for the advice , I will give it a try.

Comment: It's all I found even if it seems weird to me. I'm a MySQL user ^^

Comment: Workaround? Guess that depends on where you come from. Being used to simple arithmetic you might wonder why on earth you need a special function to add a value to a date.

Comment: @Rene There are reasons to not rely on simple arithmetic to do date calculations. If I want to add a month, I wouldn't use simple day arithmetic and instead use andr's answer below since it would account for different number of days in different months. Same with years. I don't want to think about leap years. I just want to add/subtract years. E.g. this gives the same day of the same month regardless of leap years:     
SELECT SYSDATE, SYSDATE+interval '-1' year, SYSDATE+interval '-2' year, SYSDATE+interval '-3' year, SYSDATE+interval '-4' year FROM dual Down-voting yours and upping Andr's.

Answer (score 8):

Besides adding numbers to dates - though it's the simplest way - you can add intervals like that:

```
date1 := date2 + interval '1' day;
date1 := date2 + interval '2' month;
date1 := date2 + interval '3' year;
```

It's almost the same but I prefer latter for better readability.

Comment: Yes , I created mine like this as well;).