# Equivalent function for DATEADD() in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to get a date that is 6 months from the system date in Oracle.
 And I have to get it by running an open-query from SQL. `DATEADD(MONTH,-6, GETDATE())`  function serves the purpose in SQL.
Does the function `DATEADD(MONTH,-6, GETDATE())` in SQL have an `equivalent` function in Oracle?

Comment: `ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,stepValue)` also `SYSDATE - interval '6' month`, if you want to do the operations from start of the current month always, `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MONTH')` would give that.

Answer (score 39):

**Method1:** [ADD_MONTHS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm)

`ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6)`

**Method 2:** [Interval](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions009.htm#SQLRF52064)

`SYSDATE - interval '6' month`

**Note:**
 if you want to do the operations from start of the current month always, `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MONTH')` would give that. And it expects a `Date` datatype as input.

Comment: just be careful with intervals, try this: `select to_date('31082014' , 'DDMMYYYY') + interval '1' month from dual`

Comment: Adding more context to the previous comment. The query provided fails:[22008][1839] ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified ...because it adds 1 to the month value but there are only 30 days in September.

Comment: REturns ORA-00923: "FROM keyword not found where expected" error.

Comment: @Magier, I had the same error, which is most likely due to JDBC who can not translate INTERVAL ? MINUTE correctly (INTERVAL '?' MINUTE fails as well because no parameter is substituted at all). I settled for the other answer, + ? / 24 / 60.

Answer (score 21):

***Not my answer*** :

I wasn't too happy with the answers above and some additional searching yielded this :

```
SELECT SYSDATE AS current_date,

       SYSDATE + 1 AS plus_1_day,

       SYSDATE + 1/24 AS plus_1_hours,

       SYSDATE + 1/24/60 AS plus_1_minutes,

       SYSDATE + 1/24/60/60 AS plus_1_seconds

FROM   dual;
```

which I found very helpful. From http://sqlbisam.blogspot.com/2014/01/add-date-interval-to-date-or-dateadd.html

Comment: Oracle (21c) Documentation for datetime arithmetic is here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705

Comment: Beware that the final precision is the second. millis and microseconds are lost after such an operation. Try `SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE, SYSTIMESTAMP + 5 / 24 / 60` to convince yourself.

Answer (score 10):

Equivalent will be

```
ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -6 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--ORACLE SQL EXAMPLE
SELECT
SYSDATE
,TO_DATE(SUBSTR(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1)),1,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: The Question asked for "6 months from the system date". But your query is giving the last date of previous month. Also, according to Oracle's documentation [LAST_DAY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/LAST_DAY.html#GUID-296C7C02-7FB9-4AAC-8927-6A79320CE0C6) returns a DATE. What is the reason for doing a SUBSTR on the date?

Comment: You can easily apply it to any number of months by changing the '-1' to a '-6' for 6 month prior or use a positive number to count ahead.  I used substring because my date has a time associated and I don't want that to play into the date subtraction I will use it for.

Comment: I would use [Oracle's TRUNC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) to get rid of the time. But if stripping the things that isn't beneficial for the Question, and changing the months to subtract, your query ends up being `SELECT ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6) FROM dual`.