# When I enter a dateadd or datediff code i get this error all the time "ORA-00904 "DATEADD" INVALID IDENTIFIER."

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, dateadd

I have a university project and I have a patient table with admission and discharge date attributes. I need to delete records that are older than 7 years, I used the following code :

```
delete from patient
where dis_date >= datedadd(yy,-7,getdate());
```

I get the error

> "ORA-00904: "DATEADD" invalid identifier"

. It's the same with the DATEDIFF function. Any alternatives please?

Comment: Is this `datedadd` typo or error ?

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `DATEADD`, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405297/equivalent-function-for-dateadd-in-oracle

Comment: The 'datedadd' Is a typo, I meant to write 'dateadd'.

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `DATEADD()` or `DATEDIFF()`

Comment: [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typical way of doing this in Oracle would be:

```
DELETE FROM patient
 WHERE dis_date < TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -7*12));
```

The reason I suggest using `ADD_MONTHS()` instead of year intervals is that `ADD_MONTHS()` is leap-year safe.

Comment: Thanks @David, I think I'll use yours.

Comment: Wow thank you so much - this was exactly the solution that I needed! I can't believe this doesn't have more votes.

Answer (score 7):

You may try this:

```
DELETE FROM patient
  WHERE dis_date  < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '7' YEAR;
```

There is no function named as `DATEADD` in Oracle.

Comment: That will fail if the current date is February 29, 2016