# Spring Data/Hibernate native query returning null even though real query returns results

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

So I'm trying to use the mysql datediff functions to get an average of number of days that an invoice is old.

My query looks like this:

```
 select avg(datediff(coalesce(nullableDateTimeColumn, now()), i.createdTimeStamp)) from invoice i 
 where i.createdTimestamp >= DATE_VARIABLE_HERE and (invoiceStatus = 'TEXT_HERE' or nullableDateTimeColumn is not null)
```

and my actual spring data repo definition looks like this:

```
@Repository
interface InternalInvoiceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Invoice, Long> {

@Query(value = "select avg(datediff(coalesce(nullableDateTimeColumn, now()), i.createdTimeStamp)) from invoice i " +
            "where i.createdTimestamp >= ?1 " +
            "and (invoiceStatus = 'TEXT_HERE' or nullableDateTimeColumn is not null)", nativeQuery = true)
    BigDecimal getAverageTimeInvoiceEntryTimeForInvoicesNewerThan(LocalDateTime time);
}
```

The problem is that the result is always null, I tried setting the return type to double but that also didn't work. If I set `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL` to `DEBUG` and look at the sql the sql is correct. If I run the sql I get a number back, so I know the sql that is being run by hibernate is actually returning a result. The value being return is pretty small, normally between 0-5, so it's not some strange overflow error or anything else like that. This seems like a simple scenario, so I'm a little perplexed as to why this isn't working.

Versions:

```
Spring data: 1.9.2.RELEASE
Spring: 4.2.4.RELEASE
Hibernate: 5.0.7.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api: 1.0.0.Final
```

Comment: how does the date appear in the logs when the query executes?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'm only showing part of the repo, there are a bunch of other methods, but they aren't related in any way to this problem

Comment: Can you confirm `i.createdTimestamp` is `Timestamp` or `Date` data type.

Comment: @djointster here are the results from the trace logging:

01:16:34,628 [http-bio-8080-exec-43] TRACE      org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: - binding parameter [1] as [VARBINARY] - [2016-10-01T00:00]
01:16:34,720 [http-bio-8080-exec-43] TRACE   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor: - extracted value ([avg(datediff(coalesce(nullableDateTimeColumn, now()), i.createdTimeStamp))] : [NUMERIC]) - [null]

Comment: @AppHouze i.CreatedTimestamp is a DateTime in the DB, and is mapped to a java.time.LocalDateTime in the code

Comment: My guess is you need to use format `TO_CHAR(i.createdTimeStamp)` as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006050)

Comment: @ScaryWombat That was just dummy text since the real text is something particular to our domain, but the query that gets executed has the real value in there correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Oracle. It may helps you.

```
SELECT avg(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(
(coalesce(nullableDateTimeColumn, SYSDATE)), TO_CHAR(i.createdTimeStamp, MM')), 'YYYYMMDD')))
FROM   invoice i
WHERE  i.createdTimeStamp >= '20160401' -- for example
       AND ( invoiceStatus = 'TEXT_HERE'
          OR nullableDateTimeColumn IS NOT NULL )
```

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145825/when-i-enter-a-dateadd-or-datediff-code-i-get-this-error-all-the-time-ora-00904/29146071#29146071)