# How to specify date more than 3 years ago?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date-difference

> Display details of book published more then 3 years ago with sales of less than 10000 copies

My teacher request to modify from this

```
Select title_id , title , pubdate , current_date-pubdate, ytd_sales
from titles;
```

this is what I did

```
Select title_id , title , pubdate , current_date-pubdate, ytd_sales
from titles
where ytd_sales > 10 000;
```

but here come the problem , I can't use DATEADD , and I realize that my teacher put **current_date - pubdate** , I think he want use use other methods but I had no idea.

If using DATEADD it will come out

> ORA-00904: "DATEADD": invalid identifier

Comment: And now that you see how a question get formatted - please also do so in the future yourself. Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  `add_months()`.

Comment: but how I going use curent_date - pubdate inside of it ? I still not clear about it

Comment: but I need year ? or it should be add_years() ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent function for DATEADD() in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405297/equivalent-function-for-dateadd-in-oracle)

Comment: Hmmm...if PUBDATE is a DATE, what does CURRENT_DATE - PUBDATE return?

Comment: yes , pubdate is a date . PublisherDate , I had no idea

Comment: @BobJarvis They meant sysdate .select CURRENT_DATE,SYSDATE from DUAL;                                                                       CURRENT_DATE         SYSDATE                                                                                                 
----------------                                                                                 
06-21-2015 14:02:06     06-21-2015 14:02:06

Comment: @MahendarMahi - the purpose of my posting was to try and get OP to think. Whether SYSDATE or CURRENT_DATE is used is immaterial - what I'm trying to get OP to figure out is "What kind of value is returned by SOME_DATE - SOME_OTHER_DATE, and what does it represent?". Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis got your point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you the below:

```
alter SESSION set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ;

--select * from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

create table TITLES( title_id number(10), title  varchar2(20), pubdate date, ytd_sales number(10));

insert into TITLES values(101,'ABC',TO_DATE('07-13-2011','MM-DD-YYYY'),20000);    
insert into TITLES values(102,'DEF',TO_DATE('07-13-2014','MM-DD-YYYY'),90000);    
commit;

Select title_id , title , pubdate , round( (trunc(sysdate)-pubdate) /365)  years, ytd_sales
from TITLES
where ytd_sales > 10000
and  round( (trunc(sysdate)-pubdate) /365) > 3 --this will check for the pub date > 3 years
;
```

> OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: omg , it works , but I got few question to ask , what does the round for ? Trunc?

Comment: TRUNC will give you date  alone (removing the time stamp) and round will give exact year (rounds off the days). Just try this -- select sysdate,trunc(sysdate)  from dual;

Comment: why we need need to removing the time stamp ? I assume that by using the round , we could take of the days so that we could more easily find the years? By the way , why do we need /365 ? , Sorry I'm kind of bad on logical thinking :(

Comment: Subtracting two dates give you days. To convert into years we divide by 365 (1 years =365 days) .Yes you can replace with current_date  instead of sysdate(this has timestamp) then  round( (current_date-pubdate) /365) > 3

Comment: OMG  I got it , never though about it . Last question , I don't get it what do you mean TRUNC will give you date alone. Finally , really appreciate your help , you're awesome ! :)

Comment: The TRUNC (date) function returns date with the time portion of the day truncated to the unit specified by the format model fmt. The value returned is always of datatype DATE, even if you specify a different datetime datatype for date.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's about like this.

```
Select title_id , title , pubdate , current_date-pubdate, ytd_sales
from titles
where ytd_sales > 10 000;
AND pubdate < add_months(sysdate, -36)
```

Comment: Just make sure you fully understand the function, and how it's used before you use it in any assignment.  It doesn't help you at all to finish an assignment but not understand how it works.

Comment: SQL> Select title_id , title , pubdate , current_date-pubdate, ytd_sales
  2  from titles
  3  where ytd_sales > 10000
  4  AND current_date-pubdate < add_months(sysdate, -36);
AND current_date-pubdate < add_months(sysdate, -36)
                         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

Comment: I edited the AND statement, but I'm not sure... I'm not very good with Oracle yet.

Comment: Is the datatype of Pubdate actually a date or is it an int?

Comment: actually it is a date

Comment: Perhaps you meant `ytd_sales < 10000`.