# How can I get the value of add_month in this circumstance

Tags: sql, oracle

Write a SQL query to list the MEMBERSHIP_ID, CUSTOMER_ID and the dates on which the club membership expire. (Please note, DURATION column in club_membership table represents number of months)

It looks like that I need to add between membership_date with duration. Yes, I know how to get the answer if the given duration is specified as 10/10/2008. However, the durations are multiple rows that 4, 2, 5. How can I get the date of membership expire?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405297/equivalent-function-for-dateadd-in-oracle

Comment: When does membership expire: `membership_date + duration` or `membership_date + duration+1`

Comment: "Yes, I know how to get the answer if the given duration is specified as 10/10/2008" - Really? Looks like a date to me. A duration is something like 10 days or 5 months or 3 seconds, but certaily nothing like 10/10/2008.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ADD_MONTHS( date, integer )`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm) function:

```
SELECT membership_id,
       customer_id,
       ADD_MONTHS( membership_date, duration ) AS expiry_date
FROM   table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    memership_id,
    customer_id,
    ADD_MONTHS(membership_date,Duration) as MemberShipExpire
FROM club_membership
```

Comment: `DATEADD` is an SQL server function that does not exist in Oracle.

Comment: Does the question mention if he is asking in Oracle. Tag has both Oracle and SQL

Comment: SQL is the language, Oracle is the DBMS featuring SQL. SQL Server is another DBMS featuring SQL.