# Oracle 11g date_add

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

i have  a question about the function  date_add
i searched a lot in google about the function but the function always have 2 parameters  only
but in my exemple  it uses  3 parameters ...

the exemple :

```
date2:=date_add('MM', 1, DPF_DATE_FIN_PRD);
```

so  how does it works ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent function for DATEADD() in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405297/equivalent-function-for-dateadd-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

There's no `DATE_ADD` function in **Oracle**. MySQL has it.

If you want to add any number of days to a `date` datatype value, you can e.g. (date format is `dd.mm.yyyy`):

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate) + 2 result from dual;

RESULT
----------
07.07.2021
```

or

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate) + interval '2' day as result from dual;

RESULT
----------
07.07.2021

SQL>
```

---

As you commented that function exists and *works*, then it is a custom function so you should review its code and see what it does & what parameters it expects. How? Query `user_source`. To illustrate it, I created a `date_add` function in my schema.

```
SQL> set long 10000
SQL>
SQL> select text
  2  from user_source
  3  where name = 'DATE_ADD'
  4  order by line;

TEXT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
function date_add (par_datum in date, par_days in number)
  return date
is
  retval date;
begin
  return par_datum + par_days;
end;

7 rows selected.
    
SQL> select date_add(sysdate, 2) result from dual;

RESULT
----------
07.07.2021

SQL>
```

Comment: but the code" already contais this function and the code  compiling fine

Comment: Then it is a custom function; you should review its code and see what it does and what those parameters represent. I edited the answer to show *how* to do that.